# Checking a variable for value after initializing with null in javascript

Tags: javascript, logic

I found this piece of code here: https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2015-04-30-google-maps-geolocation-tracking-in-realtime-with-javascript/

[image]

And my first thought was: The programmer must have made a mistake.

But my second thought was: Well, this is javascript, it surprised me before...

How is it possible for the variable *locationMarker* not to be **null**? Or is it some illogical "*fail safe*"?

Comment: It's not, `locationMarker` would be null, but as the comment says, if for some reason it's not null, which seems unlikely, go to the nearest exit and return as soon as possible. Of course, that code example also tries to return from an asynchronous method, which isn't possible, so it could just be that the developer is completely useless.

Comment: Could be using a closure (somewhere). Still, I don't think this code makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get the location of the user's browser using the native geolocation service.
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    function (position) {
        // Check to see if there is already a location. There is a bug in FireFox where this gets invoked more than once with a cached result.
        if (locationMarker){
            return;
        }
```

Firefox has a bug that will apparently fail to set the location if the location is not null. This includes updating location. This may not be relevant any longer, but it was apparently an issue in FireFox during 2011.

I found an article that addresses this in the comments here: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2023-geocoding-a-user-s-location-using-javascript-s-geolocation-api.htm from user heriyanto

The comment was as follows:

> I have finally found the error, when I turn on the firebug console, it shows me an error that says the marker is null when the
>   updateMarker function executed, so I try to change the updateMarker
>   with
>
> locationMarker = addMarker( position.coords.latitude,
>   position.coords.longitude, "Newer Position" );
>
> And the browser finally show me my current location, I don't know why
>   Firefox fail to make "Initial Position" so locationMarker variable is
>   still null, so when updateMarker is executed the console return an
>   error.

I would say, try it without that code. There is honestly no logical reason to check if a variable is null after setting it to null except in the unlikely circumstance of there being a bug that requires it. I would venture that the bug is likely fixed after 5 years, but you never know!

Comment: Can you expand on your answer? Answers should work even if their links break, and this one could use much improvement

Comment: In your link the variable is declared outside navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition so that make sense, but in my example is just a local variable, it should be null even if it's called twice, right?

Comment: It's just unnecessary code in that blog example. Ignore it.